# Is it possible to send as parameter an attached property on a multibiding?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to use an attached property as parameter of a Multibinding? How?

I need to use the value of an attached property to change the text I bind to a TextBlock.

My code is similar to this:

**TextBlock Binding**

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="myTxt" 
        wpfApplication2:TextBlockAttachedProperties.MyProperty="true">
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CustomConverter}"  Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="true">
        <Binding Path="Test"/>
        <Binding ElementName="myTxt" Path="MyProperty" Mode="OneWay"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

My converter:

**Converter Code**

```
 public class CustomConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double? value = null;

        value = values[0] as double?;
        DependencyProperty myProperty= null;

        if (values.Count() > 1 && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) 
            //Do something

        if (myProperty!= null )
        {
            //here do something with the value using the attached property
            var convertedValue = value; 

            return convertedValue;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object[] values = { value };
        return values;
    }
}
```

However since I don't know how to pass the attached property as a parameter of the Multibinding the converter always gets DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MultiBinding should look like shown below, where the name of the attached property is written in parentheses (see [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx)):

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CustomConverter}">
    <Binding Path="Test"/>
    <Binding Path="(local:TextBlockAttachedProperties.MyProperty)"
             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Moreover, the type of the property in the value converter is not `DependencyProperty`, but just `bool` (i.e. the type of `TextBlockAttachedProperties.MyProperty`):

```
bool myProperty = (bool)values[1];
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried something similar, but not quite right, also I was unsure of the type of myProperty inside the Converter, it makes sense that is directly a bool.